# Loop through ArrayList to display in multiline ListView in second Activity Java?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have created a second Activity to display all the elements in an ArrayList. For example if the ArrayList contains following in the MainActivity:

```
//This is an Object type
thingsList = ["This is list1","This is list2"]; 

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle;
b.putString("Lists", thingsList.toString());
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

And I have this in my Activity2.java

```
ListView newListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.newListView);
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String newList = b.getString("Lists");
ArrayAdapter adapterList = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_label, Collections.singletonList(newList));
newListView.setAdapter(adapterList);
```

What it does right now is:

```
[This is list1, This is list2]
```

How can I loop through the arraylist and make it display on different lines

```
This is list1
This is list2
```

I tried doing this but didn't work

```
thingsList = ["This is list 1","This is list 2"];

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle;
for (Object makeList: thingsList) {
    b.putString("Lists", makeList.toString());
    intent.putExtras(b);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

What it does is only grabs the last element in the arraylist like

```
This is list2
```

Thanks in advance and not sure if the question makes sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `Bundle.putStringArrayList()` instead of `putString()`. And, when working with `Intent`s, you can actually skip the `Bundle` step and add extras directly to the Intent (Android will create and populate the Bundle for you behind the scenes).

I don't know exactly how you're getting the `thingsList` reference, but if it's just a generic `List` the safest thing to do is construct a new `ArrayList` right before adding it to the bundle.

```
thingsList = ["This is list1","This is list2"]; 

// you can skip this if thingsList is already an ArrayList
ArrayList<String> thingsArrayList = new ArrayList<>(thingsList);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Lists", thingsArrayList); // or use thingsList directly
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, on the other side, you'll want to fetch it as a `List`. Again, you can skip the `Bundle` and just access the `Intent` extras directly:

```
ListView newListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.newListView);
List<String> newList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Lists");
ArrayAdapter adapterList = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_label, newList);
newListView.setAdapter(adapterList);
```

Comment: I didn't knew there was "List" method to do that. Made it way easier. This answer has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes the appropriate way is as Suggested by @Ben P.

I am just pointing out the mistake in the method you have tried.

```
thingsList = ["This is list 1","This is list 2"];

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle;
for (Object makeList: thingsList) {
    b.putString("Lists", makeList.toString());
    intent.putExtras(b);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

As the Bundle object is being created out side the for loop hence the last value will be overriden by the previous.

You should make new object evry time as below

```
 for (Object makeList: thingsList) {
        Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putString("Lists", makeList.toString());
        intent.putExtras(b);
    }
```